# balance package not found

Tags: packages, miktex

I am getting following error in LaTeX Windows version in Wineditor:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `balance.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Answer (score 1):

`balance.sty` is part of the [`preprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/preprint) bundle. The most recommendable way is to install `preprint` using the package manager of your distribution.

For completeness, of course you could download `balance` from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preprint) (.dtx and .ins file) and run the .ins file with LaTeX. Further explanation on installing can be found on this site.